# Listview updated automatically, but why?

Tags: android

This is my Code:

http://pastebin.com/GnALcSPn

The question is, why is the Listview getting updated after clicking the Okay button. I know that I added an item to my Arraylist but why do I not need something that refreshes the listView or adapter... I don't get it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of the `ArrayAdapter` is to automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when an item has been `add()`, `remove()`, `insert()`, `clear()`, etc. In your case you're adding an item to the list which is used by the adapter, so the adapter is notified automatically.

You can change this behaviour by calling `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false)`. Just keep in mind that `notifyDataSetChanged()` overrides the `notifyOnChange` back to true, so if the former method is called you'll have to set `notifyOnChange` again.